# mongoengine update multiple documents

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a list of Document objects, which have an existing `id` in the database. I've updated them, and now I'd like to put them all ack into the database at their existing ids. Is there a way to do this in one query?

An example

```
def _update_podcast(podcast):
    data = fetch_podcast(podcast.url)
    podcast.url = data.url
    #... more similar updates to podcast

def update_podcasts()
    podcasts = Podcast.objects(last_updated__lte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600))
    for p in podcasts:
        _update_podcast(p)
    # At this point, every podcast in podcasts is updated.
    # Now how do I save the modified podcasts with a single query?
```

Comment: how do you update "them" in the first place, individually or?

Comment: @Anzel You can save an existing model using `instance.save()`. You can update a document atomically using `instance.modify()`, and you can update multiple documents atomically using `MyDocumentClas.objects.update()`. The problem is that I need to do the update inside my application, so I can't do it atomically, because I'm fetching new data based on the previous data.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but I'm well aware of how to perform "update" in mongodb, what I'm asking you is "how", because without showing any of your code and what actually you want to achieve -- like you just mentioned the updates are based on newly fetched data... so if you can edit and add some useful code/information, others (perhaps me too) would likely to help you.

Comment: I'll try to put up a simplified version of my code. The actual code will happen in several stages of a Celery pipeline, but I'll put it into one function here.

Comment: that will be great :) as far as I understand and guess what you're trying to do, if the final updates are in batch where the field(s) to be updated are the same, you may just perform a bulk update at the final stage. However if update(s) in individual document varies at different stages, I think you cannot perform this in one query. JavaScript pipelines may be a better solution... but hey let see what your edits and we will look at it again together :)

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm basically fetching a podcast feed. I cannot predict what may have changed about a podcast. The only thing that is guaranteed to remain the same is the url.

Comment: And how's your `Podcast` objects look like? As a guess, you are trying to update the podcasts in mongodb periodically to reflect new changes from the web, and are your `_id`s fixed or can be dynamic? You can purge the old records and build new ones with your queue task using `json`, and insert new docs in one command.

Comment: Ids are static, but never shown to the outside (anyone using the api). As far as others are concerned, a podcast's url is its id. Can you point me to some documentation for `json`? Ican't find a json method in the api docs.

Comment: when I say `json` I mean build your new changes to a json file (or perhaps jsonlines) to import them back in bulk at final stage. But if you require to keep the `_id` and which the fields updated are not the same, I am afraid you need to update them individually on separate queries. Let me double check if mongo 3.0+ has any new supports to this.

Comment: As far as I read, there are currently no support for your use case, if you rely on previous updated data. Or best is to put individual update query in `bulk` and `execute` at final stage but I don't think it's a good idea as you may have lost updates due to unexpected `fetch` errors etc.

Comment: Is bulk documented somewhere? I only see `in_bulk` to load multiple objects by id.

Comment: You can use `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` or `initializeOrderedBulkOp()`, and pipe the queries into `Bulk` builder and `execute` at final stage. I think really the best approach for your use case is to append your new updates into a json file (or jsonlines), and at final stage read the file and perform a `bulk.execute`, in this case you will  have a backup data in case any stage fails (and risk losing your non-updated data). Let me search for the docs on `Bulk`

Comment: here we go: [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#methods)

Comment: and for [pymongo Ordered Bulk Write Operations](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I could have looked that up myself. It just wasn't clear to me that you were talking about pymongo, not mongoengine.

Comment: lol I even missed the point that you're using `mongoengine`. I'm not familiar to `mongoengine`, as almost always I just use `pymongo` and create wrapper with it or just javascript to perform the crud. I guess you can extend with a few functions to your object and call pymongo directly?